# when trying to open an activity from gridview facing error

Tags: android, gridview

When trying to open an activity its showing error that activity cannot be instantiated.I had a gridview which has to open different activities, when the gridview is in mainactivity, no problem but when the grid view is in another activity, problem araises

package com.guru.finalpro1;

public class Level1 extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_level1);
    GridView gva= (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);


    gva.setAdapter(new ImageAdaptera(getApplicationContext()));
     gva.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
       switch(position){
            case 0:

              {

                    Intent intenta = new Intent (Level1.this, AA.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


                    startActivityForResult(intenta,0);

                }

                break;

            case 1:
            {
                Intent intentb = new Intent (Level1.this, AB.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivityForResult(intentb,0);
            }
               break;


      case 2:
    {
        Intent intentc = new Intent (getBaseContext(), AC.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivityForResult(intentc,0);
    }
   break;
```

case 3:
    {
        Intent intentd = new Intent (getBaseContext(), AD.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivityForResult(intentd,0);
    }
   break;

case 4:
        {
            Intent intente = new Intent (getBaseContext(), AE.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          startActivityForResult(intente,0);
        }
      break;

```
      }}
```

Error:

10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.guru.finalpro1/com.guru.finalpro1.AA}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1853)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.guru.finalpro1.AA.(AA.java:26)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
10-12 04:55:13.543: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     ... 11 more

Comment: Please paste code of your both activities you are displaying `gridview` in.

Comment: can you please paste you code in AA.java line 26 (AA.java:26)

Comment: show your code for `AA.java`